# How to remove multiple sequential items of an array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, methods

I am curious to know how I can quickly and most efficiently remove a number of items from an array in JavaScript without creating a loop.

EXAMPLE:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
array.remove[0..4]; //pseudo code

console.log(array);//result would then be [6,7,8,9]
```

Is there a function for this, or is a custom loop required? Rudimentary question I suppose, but just wondering out of curiosity.

Comment: you can get a subset of an array in javascript with slice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
array.splice(0, 4); // returns [1,2,3,4]
console.log(array); // logs [5,6,7,8,9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use .slice() on the array.

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
array = array.slice(5,array.length);
```

Comment: [].slice() never removes items from an array, it creates a new array.

Comment: And then assigning it to the original object array in effect removes the items.

Comment: Good point - a nice solution, although it does create a new array. Thanks Bradley!

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter` method

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], b = [];
b = a.filter(function(element, index){ return index > 4 });
```

Output of `b[]`

```
[6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: [].filter never removes items from an array, thankfully.